# Magento template not showing styles

Tags: php, magento

I have installed a theme in my magento store. I had created a custom module and in the controller i am loading a phtml file,But the phtml file doesn't show any styles of my theme.

```php
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('availableorders/display')
    ->setTemplate('availableorders/display.phtml');
```

Comment: it might be the case that your custom module phtml is overwriting your theme phtml and hence style is not loading. first give details what you have done in your custom module

Comment: better place to ask this question is http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i have created a custom module called Custom_AvailableOrders in which customers can add multiple items to cart, For this i had created a form for the customers to enter multiple products and when this form is submited its values is posted to indexcontroller.php and then i am  filtering this products based on their stockavailablity and displaying them in display.phtml file as a new table.

Comment: $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')
   
   ->setData('products_notavailable',$Not_available_products)
   
   ->setData('products_available',$available_products)
   ->setData('quantity',$submit_qty)
   ->setTemplate('availableorders/display.phtml');
   $this->renderLayout();
   $this->getResponse()->setBody(
   $block->toHtml());